# Cron php code and simulate browser execution

Tags: javascript, php, cron

Through php code, html code is generated with javascript. In it, html2canvas is used to save a part of the page on the server.
The same code is executed from a programmed task (cron), but since it is not executed from a browser, it does not produce the image (jquery $(document).ready(function ()) ... it can not be invoked).

How can you simulate the original behavior from a scheduled task? 
Otherwise, how can php do something similar to html2canvas (js)?

Thaks!

Comment: Since PHP has absolutely zero to do with rendering HTML, you need at the very least a *headless browser* running on your server. Research into that direction.

Comment: thank @deceze I'm trying to have a browser installed with my server provider